# Why Spring @Transactional stops taking element from a blocking queue?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, transactions, annotations

I'm using a BlockingQueue to pass elements from provider to consumer, and it works fine.

To rollback the database operations when exceptions happen, I add the annotation @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) to the provider function. Unexpectedly, this stops the consumer from reading any elements from the queue.

The provider can always successfully putting an element into the queue, but the consumer can never take an element from the queue.

Removing the @Transactional annotation, or putting the elements into the queue outside the @Transactional marked method will both fix the problem.

Here is the java pseudo code

```java
blockingQueue = new BlockingQueue();
// consumer code
while (true) {
    // take a element
    blockingQueue.take();
}

// provider code
// after removing the annotation the consumer works fine
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
provideElement() {
    // put a element
    blockingQueue.put();
}
```

I work around the problem by moving the put method out of the @Transactional code snippet. But I'm still curious: why adding the @Trasactional annotation stops the consumer from taking elements from the blocking queue?

Comment: The purpose of transactional will be defeated if you put blockingQueue.put() outside @Transactional i guess.
Why do u want to transaction and rollback here anyways. Transactional is required when writing to DB. While reading its not required (which is what i guess you are doing)

Comment: Also what would happen if producer cannot write to BlockingQueue (as it is full) and waits. You will have very long running transactions then. Maybe you would want to re-consider why you want database transaction here

Comment: @Archit I'm using a blocking queue with not limit, so the put will not waits. In fact, both reading and writing are needed in the code snippet. I think the best way is to move blockingQueue.put()outside `@Transactional`, the blockingQueue.put() will proceed if the `@Transactional` success.

Comment: ok understood. Though what you are saying should not happen ideally. Can you share a working snippet of your code in a pastebin or similar, so that I can also try

Comment: @Archit I find out the reason. Before the transaction finish, the provider already put the element into the queue. At this moment, the database has not been changed yet. However the consumer already access the database, which leads to the error.